# Why is Magento logo shown as favicon in view source even after changing it in front-end and admin panel?

Tags: magento, favicon

This question might have been asked before but didn't help.

I have changed the favicon both in front-end and adminpanel of magento. But whenever I do view source or view any particular image from site. The magento favicon shows up. This happens only in chrome.

I have flushed all cache including theme related cache, reindexed the pages and disabled the compilation.

Any related help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Browser cache. In this case - Google Chrome cache.

Comment: Yes, did that too. Still the same. Cleared cache since beginning of time. didnt help.